# Preferred method to simplify the code with "isset"

Tags: php

In the loop I had the code

```
$total[$year] += $data[$year];
```

But PHP show me notices:

- Undefined array key 2016
- Undefined array key 2017
  etc.

I write this code

```
if (!isset($total[$year])) {
    $total[$year] = $data[$year];
} else {
    $total[$year] += $data[$year];
}
```

But visually I don't like it.

Is there a way to make it more readable and easier?

Answer (score 0):

Could make it something like this:

```
$total[$year] = $data[$year] + ($total[$year] ?? 0)
```

Where the total falls back to 0 if it isn't set.